# OnPress for React Native Google Places Autocomplete doesn't work due to its parent components

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to use the `react-native-google-places-autocomplete` library within my React Native app, but I'm having an issue clicking on the suggested list.  Whenever I click on the Google suggested address, the list disappears and `onPress` doesn't grab the address. If I use the library in a component by itself without the parent components, it works perfectly fine, but only when I place the component within `keyboardavoidingview` or `KeyboardAwareScrollView`, it does not work:

This GooglePlacesInput.js component is just the standard library from the original [repository](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete):

```js
       <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder='Search'
            minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
            autoFocus={false}
            returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
            keyboardAppearance={'light'} // Can be left out for default keyboardAppearance https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardappearance
            listViewDisplayed={false}   // true/false/undefined
            fetchDetails={true}
            renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
            onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                console.log(data, details);
            }}
            textInputProps={{
                onBlur,
            }}
            getDefaultValue={() => ''}

            query={{
                // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
                key: googleAPIKeyForAutocomplete,
                language: 'en', // language of the results
                region: "CA",
                // types: '(cities)' // default: 'geocode'
                types: '',
            }}

            styles={{
                listView: {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 60,
                    left: 10,
                    right: 10,
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    flex: 1,
                    elevation: 3,
                    zIndex: 100,
                },
                textInputContainer: {
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    margin: 0,
                    width: '100%',
                    padding: 0,
                    borderTopWidth: 0,
                    borderBottomWidth: 0
                },
                textInput: {
                    backgroundColor: '#F9F5F4',
                    borderRadius: 50,
                    width: "100%",
                    height: height / 15,
                    padding: 20,
                },
                description: {
                    // color: '#ac879a',
                    fontWeight: '300'
                },
                predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                    color: '#1faadb'
                }
            }}

            currentLocation={true} // Will add a 'Current location' button at the top of the predefined places list
            currentLocationLabel="Current location"
            nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
            GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{
                // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
            }}
            GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
                // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
                rankby: 'distance',
                type: 'food'
            }}

            GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{
                // available options for GooglePlacesDetails API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details
                fields: 'formatted_address',
            }}

            filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']} // filter the reverse geocoding results by types - ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3'] if you want to display only cities
            predefinedPlaces={[]}
            enablePoweredByContainer={false}
            debounce={200} // debounce the requests in ms. Set to 0 to remove debounce. By default 0ms.
            renderLeftButton={() => { }}
            renderRightButton={() => { }}
        />
```

I'm using `Formik` for its parent component `Form.js`:

```js
        <View style={styles.container} >
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={(value, action) => submitHandler(value, action)}
                validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
                    address: yup
                        .string()
                        .min(5)
                        .required(),
                })}
            >
                {({
                    values,
                    handleChange,
                    errors,
                    setFieldTouched,
                    touched,
                    isValid,
                    handleSubmit,
                    resetForm,
                    isSubmitting,
                    }) => (
                        <View style={styles.form}>

                            <Animated.View
                                style={[styles.fieldset, addressStyle]}
                                onLayout={e => {
                                    if (addressHeight !== e.nativeEvent.layout.y) {
                                        setAddressHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.y)
                                    }
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text style={{ marginLeft: 40, marginVertical: 5 }}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: '#FF5D4E' }}>* </Text>
                                    Address
                                    </Text>
                                <View style={styles.autoComplete}>
                                    <GooglePlacesInput
                                        onBlur={() => onBlurProps('address', setFieldTouched)}
                                    />
                                </View>
                            </Animated.View>
                            {touched.address && errors.address &&
                                <Animated.Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.address}</Animated.Text>
                            }
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                disabled={!isValid || loading || isSubmitting}
                                onPress={handleSubmit}
                                style={styles.button}
                            >
                                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    )}
            </Formik>
        </View>
```

`handleChange` still has to be passed, but I want to first figure out the `onPress` situation first.

And finally, the most parent component:

```js
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} >
                <ScrollView
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
                    style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    onLayout={e => {
                        if (heightPosition !== e.nativeEvent.layout.y) {
                            setHeightPosition(e.nativeEvent.layout.y)
                        }
                    }}
                >

                    <View style={styles.form}>
                        <Form
                            submitHandler={submitHandler}
                            loading={loading}
                            heightPosition={heightPosition}
                        />
                    </View>
                </ ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Please include `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'` in your parent `ScrollView` JSX and `listViewDisplayed={false}` as per the documentation:

```
<ScrollView
  ...
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
 >
  ...
  <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    ...
    listViewDisplayed={false}
  />
  ...
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Can you help me with a workaround for this issue, please.

Comment: Make sure the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` property is set on ALL `ScrollView` parents

Comment: does not workin as of 2023

Answer (score 4):

If you need to include this component inside a `ScrolView` or `FlatList`, remember to apply the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'` attribute to all ancestors `ScrollView` or `FlatList` as per documentation. [Documentation Link](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete#use-inside-a-scrollview-or-flatlist)

Answer (score 2):

Include this property `keepResultsAfterBlur={true}`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the parent scrollViwe keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

use property

> keepResultsAfterBlur: true

this will keep results pane open and it won't get away on focus change or any other event until you explicitly close the search results.
the on press issue is due to focus and fading of results pane due to focus change on keyboard close event.